# How to Create a Python Dictionary after iterating over three Lists for matching words

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, python-re

I need to create a Dictionary after iterating over three LISTs.
For matching sentences (list_sent as KEYs) and list of words (list_wordset as VALUEs) for matching 
 keywords (list_keywords). Please see below LISTs and expected output Dictionary with explanation.  Please suggest.

```
list_sent = ['one more shock like Covid-19',
             'The number of people suffering acute',
             'people must collectively act now',
             'handling the novel coronavirus outbreak',
              'After a three-week nationwide',
              'strengthening medical quarantine']

list_wordset = [['people','suffering','acute'],
                ['Covid-19','Corona','like'], 
                ['people','jersy','country'],
                ['novel', 'coronavirus', 'outbreak']]

list_keywords = ['people', 'Covid-19', 'nationwide','quarantine','handling']
```

'Covid-19' key word is present in list_sent and list_wordset, so they are captured in Dictionary.
'people' key word is present in 2 different items in list_sent and 2 different lists in list_wordset, so they needs to be captured.  Even if single word from the list_wordset is matching with keyword, then also its a match.

**Expected Output is:**

out_dict =

```
{'one more shock like Covid-19': ['Covid-19','Corona','like'],
 'The number of people suffering acute': [['people','suffering','acute'],['people','jersy','country']],
 'people must collectively act now' : [['people','suffering','acute'],['people','jersy','country']]}
```

Comment: All keywords from list_keywords are not present in list_wordset. only 'people' and 'Covid-19' present. So output Dictionary should have only these matching items from list_sent  (as KEYs) and list_wordset (as VALUEs).  Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to use all 3 lists, to create the required output in Dictionary format.  To remove empty Values, used additional step.

```
out_dict = {sent: [wordset for wordset in list_wordset if any(key in sent and key in wordset for key in list_keywords)]
 for sent in list_sent}
```

Results:

```
{'one more shock like Covid-19': [['Covid-19', 'Corona', 'like']],
 'The number of people suffering acute': [['people', 'suffering', 'acute'],
  ['people', 'jersy', 'country']],
 'people must collectively act now': [['people', 'suffering', 'acute'],
  ['people', 'jersy', 'country']],
 'handling the novel coronavirus outbreak': [],
 'After a three-week nationwide': [],
 'strengthening medical quarantine': []}
```

To remove the Empty List values:

```
out_dict = dict( [(k,v) for k,v in out_dict.items() if len(v)>0])
```

**Final Results:**

```
{'one more shock like Covid-19': [['Covid-19', 'Corona', 'like']],
 'The number of people suffering acute': [['people', 'suffering', 'acute'],
  ['people', 'jersy', 'country']],
 'people must collectively act now': [['people', 'suffering', 'acute'],
  ['people', 'jersy', 'country']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> {sent: [
    wordset for wordset in list_wordset if any(word in sent for word in wordset)
] for sent in list_sent}
{'one more shock like Covid-19': [['Covid-19', 'Corona', 'like']], 
 'The number of people suffering acute': [['people', 'suffering', 'acute'], ['people', 'jersy', 'country']], 
 'people must collectively act now': [['people', 'suffering', 'acute'], ['people', 'jersy', 'country']], 
 'handling the novel coronavirus outbreak': [['novel', 'coronavirus', 'outbreak']], 
 'After a three-week nationwide': [], 
 'strengthening medical quarantine': []}
```

Comment: Can we use Keywords from list_keywords for matching.  Luckily above solution is working for this example.  But i would like to depend on keywords in  list_keywords.  Please suggest.

Comment: It's not clear what that would look like, since you want the output to be in terms of the "wordsets".  As far as I can tell the "keywords" are completely redundant, since all the keywords you care about will also be in the wordsets.

Comment: All keywords from list_keywords are not present in list_wordset. only 'people' and 'Covid-19' present. So output Dictionary should have these matching items from list_sent and list_wordset.   The expected output is matching first 3 key/values pairs  from your solution, but not last 3 key/values pairs.   Please suggest to consider list_keywords also in the process.